# Check the API login limit

Tags: c#, api

How to know/inspect or check the maximum login attempt of the API Url?
I want to know so that I can set it to my sempahoreSlim

```
 private static SemaphoreSlim _semaphoregate = new SemaphoreSlim(maximumAttempt);
```

I want to avoid this error

> Log-in failed Response status code does not indicate success: 429 (Too Many Requests).

Comment: _How to know/inspect or check the maximum login attempt of the API Url?_ - without saying **what** API this is, how can you expect to get an answer?

Comment: That's an unusual status code to return for a failed login attempt, as well. Unless the API owner thinks someone is trying to crack passwords, perhaps.

Comment: Don't put semaphores in your Controllers. If you really must control your APIs, use something like Azure API Management: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/

Comment: @Andy Thanks for that I'll take a look at your link

Answer (score 0):

there is no way for you to know on the client side if you have already exceeded the access limit before trying. Unless someone creates a new EndPoint in the API for you to check if you have already exceeded access.

But you do not need to avoid this error because it is precisely that which informs you that the access limit has been reached. Just treat the http code 429 to take the necessary action in your code.